# How to remove this problem in compiling the text file?

Tags: compiling, compilation-error

I have a problem with compiling the tex file. When I use article class, it compiles but when I try a journal style, it does not compile after a certain length; it stops and tells that the label is duplicated. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsxtra,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color,colordvi}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{refcheck}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}

\newcommand\vl[1]{{\color{red} #1}}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}


\begin{document}

My text

\end{document}
```

I do not know where the problem is hidden. How can I remove this problem?

Comment: You need to get some clue why miktex fails. Check the content of the pdflatex.log file mentioned in the error message.

Comment: probably unrelated but you shouldn't be using epsfig or colordvi packages in any documents written after 1994 they have been obsolete for a quarter century.

Comment: The error message shows a complete path for pdflatex.log, starting with C:\Users\.... So it shouldn't be too difficult to find it.

Comment: copy the path and paste it into the windows explorer.

Comment: the log has dates, show the newest entries.

Comment: are you using texniccenter?

Comment: Well the error message indicates that miktex can't start the dialog to install packages on-the-fly. Try to compile once on a command line, or simply install every package in the miktex console.

Comment: Find the miktex console and learn to install missing packages, start with the lineno package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you so much. I updated the packages in the console and it worked, but, now, I have another problem! It says that environment frontmatter undefined and \begin{frontmatter}?